# How to exclude null field values from RequestBody for a REST API?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Below is my controller.

```
import com.example.springbootnonnull.dto.Product;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class NonNullController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/update-product/{product-id}", method = RequestMethod.PATCH)
    public ResponseEntity<Product> updateProduct(@RequestBody Product productDto, @PathVariable (“product-id”) String productId) {
        if (productDto != null) {
// do update operation and return 
            return new ResponseEntity<>(productDto, HttpStatus.OK);
        }return null;
    }
}
```

Request body POJO class:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import lombok.Data;

@Data
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class Product {

    private String name;
private String productId;
    private String productNo;
    private String targetArea;
    private int minimumQuantity;
    private double buyingPrice;
    private int quantity;
    private String selfStatus;
    private double sellingPrice;
}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.8</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-non-null</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>spring-boot-non-null</name>
    <description>spring-boot-non-null</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

Json Request from postman

```
{
    “targetArea: “12345”,
    "name": "Bucket",
    "productNo": null
}
```

Expectation: I want the "productNo": null field values to be excluded in the request body.
After going through other similar questions in stackoverflow, I have used @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true) as well as @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL) annotations on the class level. For response, I am able to exclude the null field values but while sending the request I want to exclude the null field values.

Comment: what exactly you mean by ignore null fields? like if sending a certain field with null value, not to override an existing value in the database?
I noticed your enpoint "update-product" and method post is most likely to be used to update, that is not aligned with the rest standards. you should use POST to create new resources, PUT to update/replace and PATCH to partial update. Ideally you would also have the product id you are updating in the path and not just the request body

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by wanting to "ignore" it? What's the result you're seeing?

Comment: @Pavel my bad. I have updated the HttpMethod to PUT as per the REST standards. My requirements is to update the product name for a given product id. The expectation is to exclude the null field values from the request body.

Comment: @ThomasKåsene The expectation is to exclude the null field values from the request body while updating a resource by product id.

Comment: @psprogrammer if you want to adhere to REST standards, you can't do that with PUT either, PUT is complete replacement.

Comment: @Pavel I have updated the HttpMethod to PATCH. I wanted to exclude null field values that is being passed to the Request body while making api call to my controller.